# Android Firebase : Application getting crashed on Click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app was working perfectly. But after I added onlicklistner on copy my app is getting crashed everytime I click on refresh. 
Here is my code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {
    this.localView = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, paramViewGroup, false);
    story = (TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.story_text);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.rlLayout);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);
    imgCopy = (ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.copyStory);
    imgRefresh = (ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.refreshStory);


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("stories");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            storiesary = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                HashMap map =(HashMap) childSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map!=null) {
                    storiesary.add((String) map.get("storytext"));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG,"check your internet connection and try again");
        }
    });


    imgRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setStory();
        }
    });

    imgCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String copy = story.getText().toString();

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) FragmentHome.this.getActivity().getSystemService(FragmentHome.this.getActivity().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("cpy_quotes", copy);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(FragmentHome.this.getActivity(), "Text Copied to clipboard.", 0).show();
        }
    });
    return localView;

}

public void setStory()
{
    int arraysize = storiesary.size();
    final int arrayposition1 = (new Random()).nextInt(arraysize);
    story.setText(storiesary.get(arrayposition1));
}
```

And this is what I am getting after I click on refresh

[Android monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4iAw.jpg)

If I remove the code for copy then app is running perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arraysize = storiesary.size();
```

This can cause a NPE if `storiesary` is null. Currently you only initialize it here

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    storiesary = new ArrayList<String>();
```

which might not be executed before `setStory()` is called.

Consider initializing it in onCreateView as well, to ensure it is not null.